# Foreach dentro de foreach com elementos pai, filhos e netos

Tags: php, lógica

Boa tarde senhores, estou tentando imprimir um parágrafo dinamicamente porem estou com certa dificuldade.

Tenho o seguinte código em html:

```css
    form {} label {
      display: block
    }
    span {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      width: 40px;
    }
    ul li {
      list-style: none;
    }
```

```html
<form name="geraTabela" action="RecebeForm.php" method="POST">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="hidden" name="id_texto[]" value="1">
      <label> <span>Pai</span>
        <input type="text" name="Pai[]">
      </label>
      <label> <span>Filho</span>
        <input type="text" name="filho1[]">
      </label>
      <label> <span>Neto</span>
        <input type="text" name="neto[]">
      </label>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      <input type="hidden" name="id_texto[]" value="2">
      <label> <span>Pai</span>
        <input type="text" name="pai[]">
      </label>
      <label> <span>Filho</span>
        <input type="text" name="filho2[]">
      </label>
      <label> <span>Neto</span>
        <input type="text" name="neto[]">
      </label>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
      <input type="hidden" name="id_texto[]" value="3">
      <label> <span>Pai</span>
        <input type="text" name="pai[]">
      </label>
      <label> <span>Filho</span>
        <input type="text" name="filho3[]">
      </label>
      <label> <span>Neto</span>
        <input type="text" name="neto[]">
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!---->
  <button type="submit" name="btn">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Eu gostaria que fosse impresso o código da seguinte forma:

```
Pai 1
 Filho 1 de Pai 1
 neto 1 de Filho 1
 Filho 2 de Pai 1
 Neto 1 de Filho 2
 Neto 2 de Filho 2

Pai 2
 Filho 1 de Pai 2
 Filho 2 de Pai 2
 Neto 1 de Filho 2
```

Eu consegui 'amarrar' o Pai com os Filhos através do ID.
Estou tendo dificuldades em 'amarrar' os netos com os filhos gostaria de apenas uma luz de como realizar essa tarefa. Desde já agradeço!

```
<?Php
if(isset($_POST['id_texto'])){
$id_texto = $_POST['id_texto'];
    foreach($id_texto as $id){
        if(isset($_POST['pai'])){
        $pai = $_POST['pai'];
            foreach($pai as $pais){
                if(isset($_POST["filho'.$id.'"])){
                $paragrafo = $_POST["filho'.$id.'"];
                    foreach($filho as $filhos){
                        if(isset($_POST["neto"])){
                        $neto = $_POST["neto"];
                            foreach($neto as $netos){

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: E o php onde entra?

Comment: O formulário está correto e você só quer lidar com a impressão do POST? Porque pra mim o formulário está meio estranho.Você cita  4 netos mas no formulário só há 3, cita 2 pais mas no formulário há 3...se você puder ser mais claro em suas intenções seria melhor.

Comment: Olá Carla, obrigado por responder, usei apenas um exemplo, já que na verdade é tudo dinâmico, a minha intenção foi mostrar que pode haver vários netos, vários filhos. Obrigado!